# Wordpress ?ver=### not loading the latest child-theme styles sheet

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have WordPress theme with a child theme. After editing and saving the child style sheet, I don't see the changes. Looking at the source code, the style sheet is loaded but has this ver at the end: `style.css?ver=4.9.7`

Now, the styles show when I load `style.css` but shows an empty file with comments (the original file when first got the theme) `style.css?ver=4.9.7`

I understand that it is encouraged to have custom styles in the child theme but, then why doesn't WordPress support this?

Any advice or help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version added on function.php file, check it first

Better enqueue style on function.php like this

```
function child_themes_styles() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), wp_get_theme()->get('Version'));
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_themes_styles' );
```